# SQL SMO DLL References v12 / v11 could not load

Tags: c#, sql-server, dll, .net-assembly, smo

I have created a C# application which referenced various **v11** SQL Server SMO assemblies.  I've done this by taking copies of these, referencing them with `Copy Local=True` in the properties of the Reference, and then including them with copies of the application.  The application is deployed to 50 or so machines on our company network, some developer PCs, some servers.  I started to receive the error

> *Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=**12**.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

on some of these servers, so I took the **v12** DLL and replaced the reference with this one, assuming it would be backward compatible.  This fixed the issue on the servers which were reporting the error shown above, but now, some servers are reporting the error

> *Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=**11**.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

This error has also occurred with one or two of the other libraries in the SQL SMO namespace, I have upgraded a number of them.

What is the correct method to reference these DLLs to work across any server, regardless of which DLLs are available there?

Comment: [BindingRedirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) ?

Comment: Thanks Jester - I have now added binding redirects for the appropriate DLLs, such as:

   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>

which has solved the issue.