# Unable to load assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Managment.Sdk.Sfc version=11.0.0.0

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, localdb

I have Visual Studio 2013 Community and I have installed SQL Server 2014 LocalDB (not complete SQL Server). During installation of Visual Studio I had already checked data tools. When I want to add a data connection using `data source:(localdb)\MSSQLlocaldb` it displays an error

> Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc version v11.0.0.0 ..... bala bala".

I checked my assembly folder it already has `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc version v11.0.0.0`. So what's the problem here? And I also installed `SharedManagementObject.msi` for SQL Server 2014 - any help?

Comment: Have you checked this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566828/sql-smo-dll-references-v12-v11-could-not-load ?

Comment: I have read the article and I add this   <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" /> in web.config file still getting same error ?